# Bash - assign to an array the out put of a variable | grep "abcd" -c

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I am new to bash script and I would like to assign to an array the output of a variable using grep "abcd" -c.

Here is my code:

```
for ....
do
disUser[$i]= "$VAR" | grep "abcd" -c
echo "disuser $i" $'\t' "${disUser[$i]}"
done
```

but the output is ...
to disuser 0
to disuser 1
to disuser 2

I realize that the assignment doesn't works. Can anyone help me??

Thank you in advance

Comment: For substitution, you need to use `'` instead of `"` as I remember, so it should be: `echo 'disuser $i' $'\t' '${disUser[$i]}'`.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in output command.. I think the assignment is faulty.

Comment: If "i" is not numeric, then the array must be declared associative with the "declare" statement.

Comment: BTW, supporting the `-c` **after** the text to match isn't guaranteed by the POSIX standard for `grep`. Safer to put option flags *before* positional arguments, as in: `grep -c "abcd"`

Comment: On a larger point -- there simply isn't enough information here to provide a diagnosis that's known to be accurate, because you're leaving out too much code; what you're giving here isn't runnable, and we can't tell if you left something out because you didn't do it at all (making it part of the problem at hand), or you left it out trying to trim your post. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- particularly, the "complete" and "verifiable" sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change your assignment to be a more valid command like

```
disUser[$i]=$(grep -c "abcd" <<<"$VAR")
```

so you're using `$(...)` to run a command, and we're saving that into a variable, namely `disUser[$i]` in this case.  Inside the command can be anything, in this case we're echoing a variable and piping that to `grep -c`.

Edit: changed the command to match Charles Duffy's excellent advice to avoid a subshell

Comment: `echo "$VAR"`, not `echo $VAR`, unless you want all whitespace to be changed to spaces, globs to be expanded, etc. Even better would be to make it `grep -c "abcd" <<<"$VAR"`, getting echo out of the picture entirely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the great tips.  I think in this case since it's a `grep -c` the whitespace change wouldn't matter (unless his pattern counted on it), but the `<<<` is clearly the better way to go regardless

Comment: Depends on whether you only care if the output is 0 vs 1, or if numbers more than 1 matter; more than one match in the same line will still have a count of 1 after an unquoted echo munges everything together

Comment: ...but if you only care about 0 and more-than-0, then one shouldn't use `grep -c` at all; the right pattern to use then is `if grep -q ...; then`, relying on exit status rather than variable capture of stdout. That's more efficient, since it lets `grep` exit **immediately** on the first match rather than needing to scan the rest of input to finish counting.

Comment: Also, if one is running this with just one line and only cares about 0-or-more-than-0, better to avoid grep altogether: `if [[ $VAR = *abcd* ]]; then ...`

Comment: ...or the POSIX sh compatible equivalent to that, if one wants to run with shells that aren't bash: `case $VAR in *abcd*) found=1 ;; *) found=0 ;; esac`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I stand even further corrected.  Thank you once more!  I even had to verify what you were saying to prove it to myself, but without surprise, you were absolutely correct.